# Wait until does not wait for elements to load so data output is not correct

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

Why is it when I add time.sleep(2), I get my desired output but if I add wait until specific xpath it gives less results?

Output with time.sleep(2) (also **desired**):

```
Adelaide Utd
Tottenham
Dundee Fc
 ...
```

Count: 145 names

Remove time.sleep

```
Adelaide Utd
Tottenham
Dundee Fc
 ...
```

Count: 119 names

I have added:

```
clickMe = wait(driver,    13).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,    ("#page-container > div:nth-child(4) > div >    div.ubet-sports-section-page > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div >    div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.page-title-new > h1"))))
```

As this element is present on all [pages](https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay).

Seems to be significantly less. How can I get around this issue?

Script:

```
import csv
import os

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_window_size(1024, 600)
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get('https://ubet.com/sports/soccer')



clickMe = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//select[./option="Soccer"]/option'))))

options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//select[./option="Soccer"]/option')


indexes = [index for index in range(len(options))]
for index in indexes:


    try:
        try:
            zz = wait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '(//select/optgroup/option)[%s]' % str(index + 1))))
            zz.click()
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

        from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
        def find(driver):
            pass

        from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException, NoSuchElementException
        import time
        clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("#page-container > div:nth-child(4) > div > div.ubet-sports-section-page > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div.page-title-new > h1"))))

        langs0 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(
            "div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.collapse > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.small-collapse.medium-collapse > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.lbl-offer > span")
        langs0_text = []

        for lang in langs0:
            try:
                langs0_text.append(lang.text)
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                pass


        directory = 'C:\\A.csv' #####################################
        with open(directory, 'a', newline='', encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            for row in zip(langs0_text):
                writer.writerow(row)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass
```

If you cannot access page, you need vpn.

Updating...

Perhaps that element loads before others.  So if we changed it to datascraped (not all pages have data to be scraped).

Add:

```
try:
    clickMe = wait(driver, 13).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ("div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.collapse > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.small-collapse.medium-collapse > div:nth-child(3) > div > div > div > div.lbl-offer > span"))))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    pass
```

Same issue still present

Manual steps:

1. opened the page https://ubet.com/sports/soccer/nexttoplay/
2. Clicked on Next to play under choose competition
3. click first element in the drop down (for me England Premier)
4. Wait for page to load through waituntil 'team name' is present.
   'team name' is defined below.
5. Scrape data 'team name'
6. Scrape data 'team name' for all elements in the dropdown.  So next would be
   England Fa Cup for me.  We want to scrape all the data 'team name' until it goes
   through entire dropdown.

team name =

```
div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.collapse > div > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div > div > div > div.row.small-collapse.medium-collapse > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > div > div.lbl-offer > span
```

Comment: I am able to access the page in your Question now but can you sum up the `Manual Steps` you are trying to `Automate`?

Comment: @DebanjanB Sure thing.  I updated my question with my manual steps I am automating

Comment: You are not getting any answer cause the description you have provided has made your attempt even vague. Please try to bring the clarity by detailing something like. `1.opened the page 2. clicking on MILLWALL at the left side and so on`. Hope you got what I meant @The Gman.

Comment: @Shahin Thanks for your feedback.  I updated the question in response to your feedback.  I hope this is somewhat clearer if not please say so :)

Comment: Now it makes sense. Thanks for the edit.